What is the Greek interpretation of Mark 4:21
What did Jesus mean by a light on a lampstand in Mark 4:21?

And He was saying to them, "The lamp is not brought in so that it
might be put under the basket, or under the bed. Is it not that it
might be put upon the lampstand?


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics SE! We are glad you are here. Please take a moment to take the site tour and check out educating new users and the FAQs. We're passionate about high quality questions and answers. Also consider going through the Help Centers sections on asking and answering questions.

Jesus' teaching about "light" is actually a well-used metaphor which He used in three ways:
1. Jesus is the Light of the World

John 8:12 - Once again, Jesus spoke to the people and said, “I am the light of the world. Whoever follows Me will never walk in the darkness, but will have the light of life.”
John 1:4, 5 - In Him was life, and that life was the light of men. The Light shines in the darkness, and the darkness has not overcome it.

This directly reflects (no pun intended) and alludes to the OT declaration:

Ps 27:1 - The LORD is my light and my salvation— whom shall I fear?
The LORD is the stronghold of my life— of whom shall I be afraid?

2. Christians reflect Jesus' light by virtuous acts

Matt 5:14-16 - You are the light of the world. A city on a hill cannot be hidden. Neither do people light a lamp and put it under a basket. Instead, they set it on a stand, and it gives light to everyone in the house. In the same way, let your light shine before men, that they may see your good deeds and glorify your Father in heaven.

3. Light represents great final judgement when all will be revealed

Mark 4:21, 22 - Jesus also said to them, “Does anyone bring in a lamp to put it under a basket or under a bed? Doesn’t he set it on a stand? For there is nothing hidden that will not be disclosed, and nothing concealed that will not be brought to light.

Thus, in Mark 4:21, 22, Jesus explains the metaphor of "light" by saying that all people's actions will be revealed.  This is a teaching directly from Eccl 12:13, 14 -

When all has been heard, the conclusion of the matter is this: Fear
God and keep His commandments, because this is the whole duty of man.
For God will bring every deed into judgment, along with every hidden
thing, whether good or evil.

We also have the great promise of Jesus based on divine grace:

John 5:24 - Truly, truly, I tell you, whoever hears My word and
believes Him who sent Me has eternal life and will not come under
judgment. Indeed, he has crossed over from death to life.

Only the wicked fear judgement; the righteous are no less sinful but are simply forgiven.
